# Access Error trying to combine tables

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Sorry if it's something really simple im a novice. Ive been trying to combine two tables and cant get it done. Trying to add Number of Employees to the other table.

[image: Table Q9r]
[image: Other Table]

```
SELECT [Training History].JobID,
    (
    SELECT Job.Department 
        FROM Job 
        WHERE [Training History].JobID = Job.JobID) AS Department, 
        SUM([Expenditure]) AS ExpenditureOfJob 
    FROM [Training History] 
    GROUP BY [Training History].JobID,
    (
    SELECT [Number of Employees] 
    FROM Q9r, 
    WHERE Q9r.JobID = [Training History].JobID
    )
;
```

This gives me an error in the last select statement please help :)

The Q9r table code is;

```
SELECT JobID, COUNT (*) AS [Number of Employees] FROM Employee GROUP BY JobID;
enter code here
```

Also cannot get this to work ( This is my preferable way since it can be done in a single table)

```
SELECT [Training History].JobID,(
       SELECT Job.Department 
       FROM Job 
       WHERE [Training History].JobID = Job.JobID) 
       AS Department, 
SUM([Expenditure]) AS ExpenditureOfJob 
     FROM [Training History] 
     GROUP BY [Training History].JobID,
(SELECT COUNT (*) AS [Number of Employees] 
     FROM Employee 
     GROUP BY JobID)
;
```

This doesn't work either

```
    SELECT [Training History].JobID,(SELECT Job.Department FROM Job WHERE [Training History].JobID = Job.JobID) AS Department, 
SUM([Expenditure]) AS ExpenditureOfJob FROM [Training History] GROUP BY [Training History].JobID,
(SELECT COUNT (*) AS [Number of Employees] 
     FROM Employee 
    WHERE [Training History].JobID = Employee.JobID
 GROUP BY JobID)
;
```

Comment: Test this query: `SELECT * FROM Job JOIN Department ON Job.JobID = Department.JobID;`

Comment: @R.García As a separate query? If so no it doesn't do anything

Comment: One moment I'm making the complete answer with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1):

### Your could combinate easily 2 tables of this way:

---

```
-- My way to combinates 2 tables:
SELECT Department.JobID, Department.NameDepartment,
       Department.ExpenditureOfJob, Job.NumberOfEmployees 
FROM Department INNER JOIN Job 
ON Department.JobID = Job.JobID
GROUP BY Department.JobID;
```

By the way with your query it could adapted to this form:

```
-- I suppose that the Training History & Expenditure both are the Databases_Name... 
SELECT [Training History].JobID, Job.Department AS Department, SUM([Expenditure]) AS ExpenditureOfJob 
FROM [Training History].Department INNER JOIN [Training History].JobID 
GROUP BY [Training History].JobID,( SELECT COUNT (*) AS [Number of Employees] 
                                    FROM Employee 
                                    GROUP BY JobID);
```

### In any case, I leave my tests in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da48a/5)

Comment: Hmmm thanks but I cant seem to get it to work, (Training History is a table, expenditure in a column in that table) Department is not a table its a field in the Job Table, could this be the cause? The  [Training History].Department bit what is it referencing since that doesnt exist unless its something to do with the join.

Comment: Ok, I modified the Query and the Build Schema & I edited the Link of SQL Fiddle. Take a look!

Comment: Thanks again however you've made a whole new table. I need it done without new tables for my coursework, we've been given these tables and fields to use. Sorry if i'm sounding ungrateful, I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

FROM Q9r, WHERE --> the , is unsolicited.

Comment: `SELECT [Number of Employees] 
    FROM Q9r, 
    WHERE Q9r.JobID = [Training History].JobID` 

to

`SELECT [Number of Employees] 
    FROM Q9r 
    WHERE Q9r.JobID = [Training History].JobID` 

I see the issue is with the **,** after table name Q9r

Comment: That's exactly the same as what I wrote, that doesn't work.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Job JOIN Q9r ON Job.JobID = Q9r.JobID;` Please try this query